# unexpected alignement using aligned

Tags: equations, amsmath, alignment

Consider following source

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    &\sum & e^{-\text{some long expression}} H \cdot\\
    & & e^{-\beta}\\
    &\sum &a
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The output, somewhat unexpected, looks like

[image: output code]

I was rather expecting the `e` and `a` of the second and third line to be aligned to the `e` of the first line, that is, to obtain something like

[image: desired output]

How can I obtain the desired alignement?

Comment: When using multiple `&` you need to remember to use 2n-1 `&` per row, where `n` is the number of alignments. You need to think of alignments as `left & right & (separator) left & right` so here you'll need `& \sym && e`, but will will still give you surprises as `aligned` adds space between alignments (the separator). So here it is better to use `\begin{alignat}{2} ... \end{alignat}` as it doe s**not** add space between alignments.

Comment: And for the `e^{\beta}` you'll need `&&& e^{\beta}` to make it match the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first column is right aligned, the second one is left aligned and the third one is right aligned (with space between second and third columns).

You need just two columns, with a small trick to get the spacing after `\sum` correct, namely adding an empty atom.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\sum{} & e^{-\text{some long expression}} H \cdot\\
       & e^{-\beta}\\
\sum{} & a
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]